# Criterion for MapReduce jobs getting launched in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am new bee to Hadoop, So please help me with this basic question.

When I do `"select * from table where <condition>;"` in Hive, I understand it will launch mapreduce as it need to applying filtering on the underlying HDFS files.

But when I do `select * from table` without any where clause on Hive, sometimes mapreduce is getting launched and sometimes it isn't. My understanding is that Ideally it shouldn't launch mapreduce as there is no filtering condition.

So could someone explain me why in few cases mapreduce is getting launched on Hive?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by two Hive properties

- `hive.fetch.task.conversion`
- `hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold`

A simple `SELECT` query would perform a fetch task instead of mapreduce task when `hive.fetch.task.conversion` is not set to `none`.

But if the total size of the files in the `table` exceeds the threshold value of bytes set in `hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold`, then mapreduce task will be triggered.

The default value of `hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold` is 1073741824 bytes (1GB) in Hive-0.14.0 and later.